# Undefined Behavior to take Address of End of Array/Vector?

Tags: c++, vector, undefined-behavior

I'd like to write a template function which can pass data to a C-style API (in my use-case specifically, OpenGL), using a `std::vector`. The code I came up with looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void pass_data(GLuint buffer, std::vector<T> const& data) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.size() * sizeof(T), data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

This seemed like a simple solution, until it occurred to me that `T` might have alignment restrictions that would cause `&t[1] - &t[0] != sizeof(T)` to be true, which would mean that this function would not accurately pass the whole array. So I rewrote the function to do this instead:

```
template<typename T>
void pass_data(GLuint buffer, std::vector<T> const& data) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, static_cast<size_t>(&data[data.size()] - &data[0]), data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

However, it's not clear to me that this kind of one-past-the-end access is safe (I'm pretty sure it's undefined behavior). What's the best way to ensure that my function accurately assesses the byte-size of my vector, and passes the correct parameters to the underlying C-API call?

Note: I do not want discussion about how I'm [mis-]using OpenGL. I'm just focused on the desire to accurately model a pointer + size of a vector.

Comment: I doubt you'll be allowed to create a vector like that. It guarantees contiguous storage. So can you give an example of an actual use case? I'm not saying it's impossible, but you'll have to excuse me for thinking this is a bit of a paranoid worry.

Comment: `&t[1] - &t[0] != sizeof(T)` in what case this be true? Is your `T` crossing process boundary?

Comment: Subtracting two pointers won't give you the size in bytes, it gives the size in elements which you already know to be `data.size()`. Your second example is *not* equivalent to the first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `data[data.size()]` is undefined behavior.

Luckily, you don't need any such thing, because `(char*)&data[1] - (char*)&data[0] == sizeof(T)` is in fact guaranteed for any type `T`.  So just go back to `data.size() * sizeof(T)`.

But I would also add a

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "Invalid type");
```

to be a bit safer.